# Ionic disabling can-swipe-back not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 1.x and have a view where I want to disable swipe back. I have tried to do that by setting the `can-swipe-back="false"` in the view:

```
<ion-view can-swipe-back="false">
```

But that hasn't disabled it from swiping back. How can I disable this?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to disable swiping back for all views or just specific views?

Comment: just a specific view